# How hard is it to convert a report running on one instance of ssrs to another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, deployment, ssrs-2008

Assuming the databases have the exact same structure(just different data)
How would this be done? I'm guessing if I give the datasources the same name I could just deploy the report(rdl) without changing anything, right? This is using ssrs 2008.

Different organizations would be using the reports on their own databases and webservers, and I'd like to know how hard it would be to deploy reports at each organization within a reasonable ammount of time.

Comment: If anyone knows anything about this I'd really appreciate an answer. even if it's as simple as "it's not so bad just use find and replace."

Answer (score 0):

We were using 2008 R2 and it was probably even easier than that.  We just swapped out connect strings and kept the datasources named the same when deploying.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the datasource's connection when you deploy, which is exactly what we do when a report runs in our dev, test then live servers which obviously have different database servers. Even your datasource name can be different , this can be set in the properties of the report once it has been deployed.

Comment: Thanks, that seems fairly straightforward. I have been wanting to get this set up for quite some time; however, I just needed to make sure it wouldn't require too much work. Really, I'm surprised a google search didn't return anything on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're setup to use shared datasources, then it's just a matter of configuring the datasource correctly on deployment.  This should really be a very easy operation.